# A generalization of Simple Vitali Lemma in the plane.

Tags: real-analysis

The following question is a generalization of Simple Vitali Lemma. Somebody can give me a sketch of the proof of this?

> Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $|E|_e < +\infty$, and let $K$ a collection of rectangles covering E. But any rectangle $R\in K$ is one of type $h \times f(h)$, where $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function and positive. Show that exist a constant $\beta >0$ (wich depend only of $f$) and a finite subcollection $R_1,\ldots,R_N \in K$ such that
>    $$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{N} R_k  \geq \beta |E|_e}.$$

I have difficult in to determine $\beta$. For example, when $f(h) = h$, we have $\beta = 1/5^2$